# What is the best way to debug a radio?

Tags: rf

I am currently programming / configuring an Atmel [AT86RF233](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf) radio and trying to get it to communicate with an digi xbee.  So far I have set the following fields on the Atmel radio:

1. extended address
2. pan ID
3. operating channel
4. not coordinator (i.e. the radio's role is a "router").

The digi xbee is still not able to discover the Atmel radio (using the ATND) command.
At a conceptual level, how can I debug something like this? Is it possible I can use a spectrum analyzer to see the RF emitted from the Atmel radio?

Would it be a better idea to get two Atmel radios to talk to each other first, and then try Atmel radio <---> digi xbee communication?

Basically my question is what is the best methodology to attack / debug a problem like this?

Comment: _Methodically._ Also, tagging this as RF is a bit misleading as your problems are software related as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already built up your radio with components like what is shown on page 10 of your link, I would first debug and double check the circuit surrounding your radio.

Then I would find a sample piece of code or instruction set that can be used to turn some settings on/off. Maybe there is already a project out there using another radio in this Atmel family. You should be able to use your computer's serial port to send instructions to the radio directly. I would use a breadboard for this.

Basically, I would try to keep it simple as possible, and then add the complexity back in when I understand each piece thoroughly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

First start with the power. after that if you use a tone generator you can start injecting the signal at the speakers and work backwards until you do not hear a tone. That will be the point at which you start looking and testing individual components. That is a quick lesson.

Comment: It is not that kind of radio.  No audio/speakers involved.